# Best practice holding data over whole application with Spring

Tags: java, spring, scope, spring-data-jpa

We introduced Spring Boot and Spring Data JPA. In the old world we have a singelton for holding data which needs the whole application (list of countries and so on). The data is stored in our database.
What is the best practice to refactor it in our new world with Spring?
Should I create a bean with application scope or is nowadays best practice to handle it with caching (@Cacheable)?

Comment: use in memeory database like H2

Comment: Use 2nd level cache. That way application code doesn’t have to know, and data can be refreshed when the cache expires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend keeping the data in your database, but caching it with a popular in-memory caching library like [caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine) or [Google Guava](https://github.com/google/guava). These libraries allow you to quickly configure an in-memory cache that can refresh the data once in a while (every 15 minute; every hour; every day; whatever you want). Your program code can hit the cache as many times as it wants, it'll always be fast. The library has the logic for periodically updating the cache.

If your data is particularly static, like application config that you may change once every few months/years, you could also consider moving it to a static config file. Spring Boot has [a wide variety nifty features](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config) built-in for loading external config (JSON or YAML) and binding it to a Java-based object model. I find the [`@ConfigurationProperties`](https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot) annotation particularly useful. The external config can either be packaged in the fat-jar, or loaded externally through Spring Config Server. The major advantage of this approach is that your config will be stored in your version control system (GIT). You can also perform boot-time validation on your config, which may reveal errors that would otherwise be revealed when your service is live. Finally, your configuration is no longer dependent on a database.

Answer (score 0):

Both approaches are OK. I prefer `@Cacheable` as it is a little bit less code to do things like conditional caching and evicting are easily available.